# Options for in-process databases under medium trust

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, database, medium-trust

I have seen a few different in-process SQL databases for .NET (including one from Microsoft), but either they do not work under medium trust (ASP.NET) or the documentation/websites don't even talk about.

What experiences have you had with in-process databases in general, and do you know of any that work under medium trust for ASP.NET?

**Update**: I know that a lot of things work in Medium trust when placed in the GAC, it acts as kind of a trust authority. However, I would prefer solutions that are bin deployable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [VistaDB](http://vistadb.net/), it works in medium trust configuration, and can be deployed in the application's **bin** file.

It also supports ASP.Net Membership API, 100% .Net, encryption, uses SQL Server syntax, etc.

Comment: Sorry for late acceptance of this, but I simply overlooked your answer.

Thanks for the good find. This was exactly the type of product I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of them will work (I *know* SQLite does) when the assemblies are stored in the GAC.

I assume you're on some form of shared hosting to experience the woes of Medium Trust. Most providers are understanding enough to add binaries to the global cache on the basis that they're third party and look fairly reputable. SQLite is well established so it shouldn't look like you're asking them to install a trojan.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will definitely look into it if nothing else shows up. Unfortunately I was kind of hoping for a bin deployable solution, as getting my ISP to put anything in the GAC is like pulling teeth :-)

Comment: Yea, GAC deployment is simply NOT the same as being Medium Trust compliant.  Bin deployment should be the only requirement.